# ahead by x commits following merge but cannot push

Tags: git, git-merge

We have a remote repo with different versions v1 through to v4, we have now gone live with v4 and are starting work on v5. 90% of all the code was created in v4. One of our devops cut a new v5 branch from master but it is missing all of v4 code.

I have checked out v5 and did the following command to merge v4 into it.

```
git merge v4
```

During which it scrolls through all of the changes we made in v4, so definitely looks good.

if I then do a

```
git status
```

it tells me that

```
    Your branch is ahead of origin/v5 by 44 commits.
    (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

which seems to contradict itself?

I then attempt to push to v5 with

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/v5
```

and it returns:

```
    Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
```

followed by:

```
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/v5 (no new changes)
error: failed to push some refs to '......'
```

No doubt I'm missing a step or have done something wrong but I can't quite work out what?

Comment: Why are you pushing to `refs/`?

Comment: To push : just run `git push`, or `git push origin v5`

Comment: The message is coherent : it states that the files on your disk match the content of your *local* branch.

Comment: I'm pushing to refs/ purely because that is the normal command we use for pushing to v4 I simply changed the v4 to v5

Comment: @ToffeeApple does LeGEC's command work for you? It should. Please provide further feedback if not. In general, I never use your push syntax, always the syntax shown by LeGEC.

Comment: The `! [remote rejected]` part, plus the `refs/for/` part, indicates that you're using Gerrit. Gerrit places additional constraints atop the normal Git ones: in this case, it probably wants you to do something with Gerrit change-IDs. Note that I don't use Gerrit and am not sure precisely what's required here, just that this isn't Git itself complaining.

Comment: @torek yes, we use gerrit, normally I would do a git commit to stage the changes for a gerrit review and then a git push (as per command above) to push it to gerrit for peer review. In this case if I attempt a commit it tells me there are no changes I can add to the commit.

Comment: I believe Gerrit change-IDs are in the *commit messages*; you should adjust the commit messages (producing new commits with new commit hashes) and then push those new commits instead of the old commits. Again, though, I haven't actually *used* Gerrit, so this could be entirely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When git is used in conjunction with gerrit then you cannot do a merge exactly as normal as gerrit cannot handle the fact you've fast forwarded and therefore does not see anything new to commit.

To get around this you need to use the "no fast forward" option when merging

```
    git merge v4 --no-ff
```

then you commit and push as normal.

Thanks to all who commented.